# producing distilled water using sun energy

Tags: energy, water

My home town (Iran, Lamerd) has very hot summer (always > 45+ degree) with dry weather and sharp sun shine. I used some black tubes under glassy box to heat up water. It was a natural thermal siphon and did not need pimping. definite volume of salty water in the container was connected to the tube glassy box. the empty space of the container was filled with hot humid. I have just connected this humid to a condenser. finally I had the distilled water but production rate was slow. Is that economically feasible to scale it up and be used for drinking water?[image: My home made apparatus]

Comment: Have a look at airwells http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_well_%28condenser%29 .

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about health and safety.